# Ajax Control Toolkit on a commercial website

Tags: asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm developing a Asp.Net website that will be used for a lot users. Would you recomend the use of Ajax Control Toolkit on these kind of website?

**Update**:

I'm trying to imagine the worst scenario. Maybe with one user it will work perfectly.

By the way, I only use this controls from Ajax Toolkit:

`ValidatorCalloutExtender`, `MaskedEditExtender` and `AsyncFileUpload`.

Thank you.

Comment: Pretty vague scenario. What kind of site, how many users, how much bandwidth is expected per user, what parts of the user experience are the most important, &c...

Comment: As KevinP says below they're not the best. Could you go with a handrolled solutiono or use something like jQuery instead?

Comment: I think I use the controls without so much problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've developed with the Ajax Control Toolkit many times, and to be honest I would not recommend it. Many controls seem like they are in the Beta stage, requiring work-around and 'hacks' to get them working under the conditions you need. I think MS dropped the ball on this product. That's just my opinion though.

I prefer commercial toolsets, and am currently quite happy with [Telerik's RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx). Great support, very good controls, stable. Not overly expensive.